# Buffered Reader cannot read my Double

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;
PrintStream streamToClient;
BufferedReader streamFromClient;
Socket fromClient;
static int count = 0;
Thread thread;

InputStreamReader((fromClient.getInputStream())));
streamToClient = new PrintStream(fromClient.getOutputStream());

double strx = streamFromClient.readDouble();
System.out.println("Radius " + strx);

double area = strx * strx;
streamToClient.println("Luas " + area);
```

I have error in code

```
double strx = streamFromClient.readDouble();
```

Anyone can help me to read "Double" in Buffered Reader?

Comment: 1) Very little of your code is relevant. 2) Your code wouldn't compile. 3) You haven't said what the error is. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Answer (score 0):

```
double strx = streamFromClient.readDouble();
```

Is not valid. `BufferedReader` does not have a `readDouble` method.

This is what you want:

```
String line = streamFromClient.readLine();
double strx = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

Be wary of `NumberFormatException` which can be thrown by `Double.parseDouble`, it is up to you if you need to handle that.

Comment: WOW Thanks. It's Work!

Comment: Happy to help. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.